# Style a point layer in MapServer 7.0.4

Tags: symbology, mapserver

I have a very simple problem with MapServer 7.0.4.

I am trying to display a point layer (WMS) with a simple circle but I can't get it to work.

Here is the CLASS definition in the layer object:

```
  CLASS

    STYLE
      SYMBOL "circle"
      SIZE 16
      COLOR 255 0 0
      OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
    END #STYLE

  END #CLASS
```

Here is the symbol definition, in a separate file called 'circle'

```
SYMBOL
  TYPE ellipse
  POINTS 1 1 END
  NAME "circle"
END
```

Here is the error from the log file:

```
[Fri Jun 16 09:47:51 2017].804000 readImage(): General error message. unsupported pixmap format
[Fri Jun 16 09:47:51 2017].804000 msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'sommets'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah.. I had to post a question to solve it moments after!

In my map file (in the map object) I put the following symbol definition:

```
SYMBOL
    TYPE ellipse
    POINTS 1 1 END
    NAME "circle"
END
```

The symbol is defined BEFORE referencing the layer files. Here is an example:

```
[.....]


  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:32198"
  END



    SYMBOL
        TYPE ellipse
        POINTS 1 1 END
        NAME "circle"
    END

    # Layers

    INCLUDE "lyr_hillshade.map"
    INCLUDE "lyr_dem.map"   

[....]
```

Then here is the CLASS object definition of the layer I wanted to style:

```
  CLASS

    STYLE
      SYMBOL "circle"
      SIZE 16
      COLOR 255 0 0
      OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
    END #STYLE

  END #CLASS
```

Comment: well saved me providing an answer...